# How can I replace a string containing special characters?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, escaping

I have a text file that contains a line with brackets, character, integers, and `:` symbols.

I want to replace `[0:1]` with `[2:4]`

```
$ cat input.txt
str(tr.dx)[0:1]
```

Expected output:

```
str(tr.dx)[2:4]
```

I tried

```bash
sed -i 's/str(tr.dx)[0:1]/str(tr.dx)[2:4]/g' input.txt
```

but it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Escape the `[`: `sed -i 's/str(tr.dx)\[0:1]/str(tr.dx)[2:4]/g' input.txt`

Comment: `sed 's/\[0:1]/[2:4]/'` should do the job.

Comment: With your posted example`s/0:1/2:4/` is all you need. If that's not all you need then you should provide a more truly realistic example including cases that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/\(str(tr\.dx)\)\[0:1]/\1[2:4]/' file

str(tr.dx)[2:4]
```

Here:

- `\(str(tr\.dx)\)` matches `str(tr.dx)` and captures it in group #1
- We need to escape the `dot` in regex
- `\[0:1]` matches `[0:1]`. Here we need to escape `[`
- `\1` is back-reference for capture group #1